# Angular 2 - Two way communication between components

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I've this code...It's a sample tutorial application I'm trying to build that's reflect the daily basis needs of a developer.
Actually, when the user types "fire" on the parent component, the child execute an event that's sends to the parent the word "booom" - It's a sample to demonstrate communication between a child component sending messages to a parent component using @Input and OnChanges.

Now, I'm trying to do different: The parent should with some how tell to the child a message like "Target Locked" to the child when the user press the enter key (keyCode == 13). With this we will have a scenario of 2 way communication between components.

What is the best approach ?

child.component

```
import {Component, Input, OnChanges, EventEmitter,Output, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
@Injectable()
@Component({
selector: 'child-component',
template: `<p>I'm the child component</p>
`
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges { 
@Input() txt: string;
@Output() aim: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    var t = changes['txt'].currentValue;
    if(t == 'fire') {
        console.log('Fire !!!');
        this.aim.emit("booom !!!");
    }
}
}
```

parent.component

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ChildComponent} from './child.component'
@Component({
selector: 'parent-component',
directives : [ChildComponent]
template: `<p>I'm the parent component</p>
<input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]="theModel" (keydown)="arrow($event)">
<p>feedback: {{feedback}}</p>
<child-component txt="{{theModel}}" (aim)="feedback=$event"></child-component>
`
})
export class ParentComponent { 
theModel;
feedback;
arrow (evt){
    if(evt.keyCode ==13) {
        //Need to cause an event on the child - a message like "Target Locked"
    };
}
}
```

Comment: Use `@Input()` to communicate from the parent to the child, and `@Output()` to communicate from the child to the parent, or use a service.

Comment: "Now, I'm trying to do different:" -- I don't see what is different here.  Just use the same input and output properties and send different messages, or add another set of input and output properties.  Also checkout the [Component Interaction cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)

Comment: The parent incorporates the child ny using import and the selector <child-component>. So, the parent can capture the (aim) event from the child. My doubt is about to do the opposite way: Child capture the event of the parent. Remember the child will never have the selector of the parent. That's why it's really different. got the point ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My doubt is about to do the opposite way: Child capture the event of the parent. Remember the child will never have the selector of the parent. That's why it's really different.

I think the confusion is around the fact that you don't need an event.  For parent → child communication, just add another input property to the child. And bind a parent property to it:

```
<child-component [anotherInputProperty]="someParentProperty" ...
```

Then, whenever you change the value of `someParentProperty` in the parent component, Angular change detection will propagate the new value to the child:

```
if(evt.keyCode === 13) {
    // Need to cause an event on the child - a message like "Target Locked".
    // Just change the property value:
    this.someParentProperty = "some new value";
    // Angular will take care of propagating the new value to the child
};
```

If you want the child to execute some logic when the input property value changes, implement `ngOnChanges()` in the child.

If the issue is that you don't want to change the message each time, then you could either

- use [a shared service with an Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35568924/215945) and have the child `subscribe()` to the Observable, or
- prefix or postfix the message with a random value, and separate it from the message with a `|` or some other character you can split on, so that in the child you can easily extract the message.

You can also use a Subject rather than an Observable in the shared service: see [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).

Comment: ty, Mark !! I will check your answer 'til tomorrow and I will not forget to mark you as answer if applicable. ty !

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I'm doing actually. Honestly it's not much elegant, but looks like it's the only one acceptable :( For example, in my real project I've an inputBox in my parent .I need to cause a reaction (event) in my child event every time the user press the arrow key. It could be up and down. So, I'm using your solution in this way: if(event.keyCode ==40){ this.myChildProperty = 'down,' + Math.random(); } - If I press the down twice, the random will ensure that the event will be executed. But honestly I really don't like this solution. But since it's the only one acceptable,ok

Comment: @MarcoS.Junior, since you keep mentioning the word "event", it sounds like the shared service approach (with an Observable or a Subject) would be more appropriate for your use case, rather than a input property.

Answer (score 3):

You could provide an `EventEmitter` as input of the child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component'
  (...)
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input()
  parentEventEmitter:EventEmitter;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.parentEventEmitter.subscribe((event) => {

    });
  }
}
```

The child could then subscribe on it to be notified...

This `EventEmitter` would be provided this way within the parent component:

```
<child-component
   [parentEventEmitter]="theEventEmitterFromTheParent">
</child-component>
```

Comment: Unable to implement: ngOnInit() {
        this.parentEventEmitter.subscribe((event) => {
    }); ---> this.parentEventEmitter.subscribe is not a function in [arrow in ParentComponent - I placed this on plunker at https://plnkr.co/edit/nqlCl6r5Ib64MCYJA5v9

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement event emitter and subscribe to it in the parent component. Your emitter name have to match the bound value name +'Change' Example: if your value name is "sum" your event need to be "sumChange" that way you can do 2 way binding from the parent like `[(sum)] = "value"`. Here is a plunk example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/efOGIJ0POh1XQeRZctSx?p=preview

Comment: Sounds really interesting, Mohy ! I will study this on monday, but I liked !

Comment: You set a value to the parent, basically. The challenge is to make the parent cause an event on child. In my example, I'm raising an event from the child to parent.

Comment: Well, if you noticed I change the value from the parent and it reflects in the child and when I change it from the child it reflect into the parent. This is very much the 2-way communication. Are you looking to accomplish something different?